# Will denial of entry to the US due to improper documentation affect travel to Canada and other countries?

Tags: visas, usa, denial-of-entry

I was denied entry to US recently because of improper documents. My passport was stamped with entry withdrawn. I have a multiple entry visa also for Canada. Will it affect my travel plans to Canada? Will it affect my visa applications in other countries? I travel a lot because of business.

Comment: What does “improper documents” actually mean?

Comment: @jcaron think of an expired passport, an expired visum, incorrect visum for the purpose of travel, possibly even a damaged passport.

Comment: @jwenting I know it could mean that. But it could also mean "forged document", "suspicion of fraud", or anything between the benign and the very serious. The consequences would vary greatly depending on the actual circumstances (though "entry withdrawn" probably points to the more benign issues).

Comment: @jcaron if he had forged documents he'd have been arrested on the spot, hence I didn't include that possibility.

Comment: **NOT A DUPLICATE** Because the questioner wasn't denied entry. (Despite what they say in the question).

Answer (score 46):

There are two kinds of ways that you get to not enter the US at a land border. The most serious is "denied entry". This means they officially refused you entry. It goes on your record in the US and you have to answer "yes " to any questions about being denied entry to a country. It will seriously affect your ability to enter the US and other countries.

The much lesser one is "application for entry withdrawn". This usually applies when the reason preventing your entry is more minor, for example not having a document you need. The technical line is that they allowed you to withdraw your application to enter the US, meaning that they did not have to deny you entry. While there is a record of this interaction, it will probably not affect your ability to enter the US or other countries (apart from maybe some additional questioning). You can truthfully answer "no" to questions about whether you have been denied entry or refused a visa.

It sounds like you have the second case, but your describing yourself as "denied entry" makes me uncertain. They should have explained this when they stamped your passport. If you have other documents from the officer, check that they tie up with what I said here.

Comment: Doesn't the ESTA application form ask if you've ever been denied entry or withdrawn an application to enter?

Comment: In that case you should answer "yes". Even then I believe "entry withdrawn" is going to be much less serious than "denied entry".

Comment: Does a rejected visa application affect future border crossings/visa applications? i.e. if someone were to be rejected for a tourist visa, would that potentially affect an application for say an academic visa?

Comment: @Max That's an entirely different question. Please ask it separately.